# state sharing with push & pull via redis

Tags: design-patterns, redis, publish-subscribe

I would like to share a state via Redis with the following requirements:

1. **Decoupling:** uncoupled publishers and subscribers
2. **Single Ownership:** each state is set by a single publisher
3. **Push:** once a state changes relevant subscribers must immediately be notified
4. **Pull:** once a subscriber initializes it should immediately pull relevant states

if PUSH was required without PULL pub\sub would be optimal
if PULL was required without PUSH a simple redis key and value would work well

What would be the best design pattern to support all requirements?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use both pub\sub to publish (push) state changes and a hash to keep the latest published state of each kind from which the subscriber can read (pull)

The only hurdle is that you need to handle race conditions as follows:

- Publisher should notify and then update the state
- Subscriber should first subscribe and then read the state